# Lemma 1.2 from Shakarchi Stein's book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I read the proof of the following lemma and understand it completely. However the proof of the second part of lemma quite unclear to me. The author consider the case when $f(x)=0$ and I understood his reasoning but I am not able to transfer this when $f(x)=0$ a.e. and in some sense I know that the property of a.e. does not change but I would like to see the rigorous and detailed proof.

Frankly speaking, I have spent many hours in order to prove it by myself but no results. So would be very grateful for help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is $m$  Lebesgue (i.e. a complete) measure? Because if so, then the DCT applies, right?

Comment: @Driver8, Yes everything here is Lebesque measure. But in this book DCT comes after this theorem. Do you know how to prove the part (2) when $f=0$ a.e.?

Comment: Is it established that $\int_{E}\varphi(x) \, dx = \int_{E\setminus Z}\varphi(x) \, dx $ for any measure-zero set $Z$ and any simple function $\varphi$? (It is in fact easy to prove!) Then you can simply replace $E$ in the theorem by $E\setminus\{f \neq 0\}$ and proceed.

Comment: @SangchulLee, your answers are great as always! Thanks a lot! Now I understand the case $f=0$ a.e.

Comment: @SangchulLee, Hi! Could you take a look at this interesting question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934902/problem-30-from-shakarchi-steins-book

Comment: @SangchulLee, Could you please take a look at the above link?

Answer (score 1):

If $f=0,$ then $\phi_n\to 0$ uniformly on $A_{\epsilon}$, so there is an integer $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $|\phi_n|<\epsilon$ on $A_{\epsilon}$. Calculating as above, we find

$|I_n|\le \int_E|\phi_n|=\int_{A_{\epsilon}}|\phi_n|+\int_{E-A_{\epsilon}}|\phi_n|\le \epsilon m(E)+Mm(E-A_{\epsilon})\le \epsilon m(E)+M\epsilon$ as soon as $n>N.$

Comment: Thanks but I know this when $f=0$ everywhere, but what if $f=0$ a.e.? Because i am not able to understand this case.

Comment: $\int_Ef=0$ on every every set $E$ of measure zero, no matter what the values of $f$ on $E$ are.